# Laravel-App with basic auth in URL: OK for web, not OK for API

Tags: laravel, nginx, basic-authentication

I try to run [Koel](https://github.com/phanan/koel/) (or [Kutr](https://github.com/X-Ryl669/kutr), a fork) behind a HTTP basic auth user/password dialog: https://koel:8001 behind an nginx reverse proxy https://koel with basic auth enabled.

Koel is a Laravel application and uses JWT tokens and the `Authorization` Header field like this:

`Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eX…`

This means that every request overwrites the basic auth header (that uses the same field) and the login dialog pops up again and again.

When I set APP_URL in the file .env to https://user:pass@koel, all links to static files are indeed properly fetched. API calls like https://koel/api/data unfortunately ignore this.

Can I use some kind of Middleware to inject user and password into the API calls?

Answer (score 0):

The principle of JWT is to avoid using basic auth which is like no authentication at all (your credential are transmitted in clear with basic authentication).

So, I'd say that JWT using `Authorization` is a good thing, since it prevents your credential from leaking in case of bad configuration.

The principle of JWT is to, upon valid credential, to generate a token that's stored in your browser (a bit like a cookie). Then, with this token, there is no need to present any authentication whatsoever (so the credentials are present only once upon authentication, no during the complete session like for a basic or digest authentication).

With Koel, you can't do much to prevent this, since there is no way to change the login page in order to use basic authentication.

With Kutr however, I've done some hooking mechanism so you can plug your own login page (which can be as simple as validating a basic authentication).

It's available [here](https://github.com/X-Ryl669/kutr/blob/master/cms_login.php.example)

In your case, replace the top of the file from:

```
// Require your CMS bootstrap code here
require_once("yourCMSbootstrap.php");
// Bootstrap your CMS and check the session is valid (if not your CMS will fallback the login screen)
checkSession();
```

to

```
// Assert the user provided an basic or digest authentication
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit();
} else {
    $login = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
    $pw = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
    if (!checkValidLoginAndPW($login, $pw))
    {
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo 'Game over';
        exit();
    }
}
```

Make sure the user's login also exists in Kutr's application

Comment: thank you for your answer! i got it working by exposing login.php (edited more or less like you suggested) to non-basic auth-world and having loginRedir.php and everything else in reverse proxy. however, leaving even a minimum footprint of my little home server visible to the wild wild web makes me uncomfortable. combined with the major delay (especially on mobile) when opening my very large library, i ditched koel and switched to ampache.